# How to use functions from a custom module in Python Django shell

Tags: python, django

I have a python file called `my_functions.py` in which I have the following code:

```
from core.models import Blog

def news(): 
    b = Blog(name='New Blog', tagline='All the latest news.')
    b.save()
```

My main app folder in django is called core and I have put my python file in there.  In the shell I am able to do the import: `from core import my_functions` 
However I get an error `AttributeError: module 'core.my_functions' has no attribute 'news'` when I try to run the code `my_functions.news()`. 
How can I run the `news` function in the shell?

My tree structure is as follows:

```
core
    -__init__.py
    -admin.py
    -apps.py
    -models.py
    -my_functions.py
    -tests.py
    -urls.py
    -views.py
```

Everthing else works as normal but I just cant seem to figure why I cant do this simple import and run the function. I'm using VSCode.

Comment: Try this `from yourjangoapp.core import my_functions`. Maybe `core` is part of some library and that could potentionally import wrong module.

Comment: @xbound that would raise `core has no attribute my_functions`

Comment: Is there a colon after `news()`? `def news():`

Comment: @West Could you post your project tree?

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks I've corrected that in the question. Error still there though

Comment: you're running a django shell I assume? Not just a python shell...

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes I'm in the django shell

Comment: Is my_functions module somehow nested in core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure there's an `__init__.py` file in the `core` directory. Then:

```
from core.my_functions import news
```

Also you have to restart your shell if you make changes to any file in your project, since the django shell will load all modules in memory at launch time.

Comment: I get an error on that: `ImportError: cannot import name 'news'`

Comment: Yes the `init.py` file is there

Comment: then we don't have information. This has to work if you have `my_functions.py` file at the same level as `__init__.py`. and if core is registered app in your django settings.

Comment: Oh I restarted VS code and it works now with your statement. Thanks! So why does importing as I did above not work?

Comment: Yours should work as well. It’s just easier to spot errors early this way.

Comment: So when I change the name of the function `news` to `news2` and save the file, the shell still runs the old `news` function and doesn't pick up the fact that the old function doesn't exist anymore. Trying to run the function with the new name `news2` throws an error. Also any other new function added to the `my_functions.py` file after I ran it the first time cannot be executed. However everything works as expected when I change the file name to something else. Not sure if its a django thing or VS code related as I'm using the VS code terminal to run the django shell but will look into this.

Comment: you have to restart your shell when you make changes. Once you've read a file, it's in memory. You don't have to restart VS code, just restart the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Create your file and write your function. In my case was:

```
# /home/$(USER)/repos/bo/apps/base/queries.py
# "apps.base", added to INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py

from apps.base.models import Player
from core.models import Blog

def news(): 
    b = Blog(name='New Blog', tagline='All the latest news.')
    b.save()
    return b


def count_player_overs():
    all_playerovers = Player.objects.all()
    count_all_playerovers = all_playerovers.count()
    return count_all_playerovers


print('count_all_playerovers: {}'.format(count_player_overs()))
print('saved news object: {}'.format(news()))
```

```
# this folder has manage.py
cd /home/$(USER)/repos/bo/
```

And run:

```
./manage.py shell -c "from apps.base import queries;"
```

Result:

`count_all_playerovers: 376`

`saved news object: New Blog`

You can change the code and run again `./manage.py shell -c "from apps.base import queries;"` and it will re-import the module and run the function with all your changes.